# Do I need to hash a Redis key before using *SET?

Tags: redis

I'm under the impression that one should hash (i.e. sha3) their Redis key before adding data to it. (It might have even been with regard to memcache.) I don't remember why I have this impression or where it came from but I can't find anything to validate (or refute) it. The reasoning was the hash would help with even distribution across a cluster.

When using Redis (in either/both clustered and non-clustered modes) is it best pracatice to hash the key before calling SET? e.g. `set(sha3("username:123"), "owlman123")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't hash the key. Redis Cluster [hashes the key](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#redis-cluster-data-sharding) itself for the purpose of choosing the node:

> There are 16384 hash slots in Redis Cluster, and to compute what is the hash slot of a given key, we simply take the CRC16 of the key modulo 16384.

You can also use [hash tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags) to control which keys share the same slot.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea if your keys are very long, as recommended in the official documentation:

> A few other rules about keys:
>
> - Very long keys are not a good idea. For instance a key of 1024 bytes is a bad idea not only memory-wise, but also because the lookup of the key in the dataset may require several costly key-comparisons. Even when the task at hand is to match the existence of a large value, hashing it (for example with SHA1) is a better idea, especially from the perspective of memory and bandwidth.

source: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/tutorial/#keys

Comment: link changed: https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace/